# I can not get the date of birth from Google Plus API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, google-plus

I am trying to get the user information's from google plus api. I am following this [Link](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Google%2B_authentication_in_Windows_Phone_application) to G+ integration. Here i can get all the information's except DOB. But now I must get the users date of birth.

I have check with this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849148/retrieving-date-of-birth-with-google-oauth-api) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612357/retrieving-date-of-birth-and-marital-status-with-google-oauth-api). But still now i can not get the DOB.

I already try to change the Scope.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

But here i am getting this error.

```
The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

Please help me to get the DOB.. Thanks in advance..

**Update Question:**

if i use this `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token` url i am getting this response:

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"Vea_b94Y77GDGgRK7gFNPnolKQw/9l0eRpGHUNy6ZNRNIEbS6cgHc3Y\"",
 "gender": "male",
 "emails": [
  {
   "value": "kathir.likes@gmail.com",
   "type": "account"
  }
 ],
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "1024703XXXXXXXXX93",
 "displayName": "C. Vijay Dhas",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "Dhas",
  "givenName": "C. Vijay"
 },
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/1024703XXXXXXXXX93",
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA
/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": true
 },
 "isPlusUser": true,
 "language": "en",
 "circledByCount": 0,
 "verified": false
}
```

if i use this `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token` url i am getting this response:

```
{
 "id": "1024703XXXXXXXXX93",
 "email": "kathir.likes@gmail.com",
 "verified_email": true,
 "name": "C. Vijay Dhas",
 "given_name": "C. Vijay",
 "family_name": "Dhas",
 "link": "https://plus.google.com/1024703XXXXXXXXX93",
 "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAA
AAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg",
 "gender": "male",
 "locale": "en"
}
```

**Here My entire code:**

```
public partial class GooglePlusLoginPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    GooglePlusTokens googlePlusTokens = new GooglePlusTokens();
    GooglePlusUserInfo googlePlusUserInfo = new GooglePlusUserInfo();

    string Parameters = null;
    string ClientId = "837597087773-9of2t72imted819fr1556t6qoj1ts6h7.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    string ClientSecret = "U8B7SdW3zmBB_k0AFCKXaE3f";
    string RedirctedUri = "http://localhost";

    [DataContract]
    public class GooglePlusAccessToken
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "refresh_token")]
        public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "expires_in")]
        public string ExpiresIn { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "token_type")]
        public string TokenType { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class GooglePlusUserProfile
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "email")]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "given_name")]
        public string given_name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "family_name")]
        public string family_name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "link")]
        public string link { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "picture")]
        public string picture { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "gender")]
        public string gender { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "birthday")]
        public string birthday { get; set; }

    }

    public GooglePlusLoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(GooglePlus_LoginPage_Loaded); //load google plus login page 
    }

    void GooglePlus_LoginPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + RedirctedUri + "&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&client_id=" + ClientId;

        var newUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + RedirctedUri + "&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&client_id=" + ClientId;

        webBrowserGooglePlusLogin.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }

    private void webBrowserGooglePlusLogin_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowserGooglePlusLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void webBrowserGooglePlusLogin_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Uri.Host.Equals("localhost"))
        {
            webBrowserGooglePlusLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            e.Cancel = true;
            int pos = e.Uri.Query.IndexOf("=");
            string messageCode = pos > -1 ? e.Uri.Query.Substring(pos + 1) : null;
            if (messageCode != null)
            {
                Parameters = "code=" + messageCode + "&client_id=" + ClientId + "&client_secret=" + ClientSecret + "&redirect_uri=" + RedirctedUri + "&grant_type=authorization_code";
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);
            }
        }
    }

    void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;              
            Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Parameters);
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            postStream.Close();
            webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
        }

    }

    void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

            using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
            {
                using (var streamResponse = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var GooglePlusSerializerData = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GooglePlusAccessToken));
                    var GooglePlusProfileData = GooglePlusSerializerData.ReadObject(streamResponse) as GooglePlusAccessToken;
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        (Action<GooglePlusAccessToken>)((GooglePlusUserData) =>
                        {
                            GooglePlusData.AccessToken = googlePlusTokens.AccessToken = GooglePlusUserData.AccessToken;
                            googlePlusTokens.RefreshToken = GooglePlusUserData.RefreshToken;
                            googlePlusTokens.ExpiresIn = GooglePlusUserData.ExpiresIn;
                            googlePlusTokens.TokenType = GooglePlusUserData.TokenType;
                            RequestForUserProfile();
                        }), GooglePlusProfileData);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error==> " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void RequestForUserProfile()
    {
        //var urlProfile = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=" + GooglePlusData.AccessToken;
        var urlProfile = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + GooglePlusData.AccessToken;        
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlProfile);
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(this.ResponseCallbackProfile), request);
    }

    private void ResponseCallbackProfile(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

            using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
            {
                using (var streamResponse = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {

                    var GooglePlusSerializerData = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GooglePlusUserProfile));
                    var GooglePlusProfileData = GooglePlusSerializerData.ReadObject(streamResponse) as GooglePlusUserProfile;

                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                       (Action<GooglePlusUserProfile>)((GooglePlusUserData) =>
                      {
                          GooglePlusData.UserName = googlePlusUserInfo.UserName = GooglePlusUserData.name;
                       GooglePlusData.UserImage = googlePlusUserInfo.UserPicture = GooglePlusUserData.picture;
                         if (GooglePlusData.UserImage == null)
                          {
                              GooglePlusData.UserImage = googlePlusUserInfo.UserPicture = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_kvINpT6jtI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/IEAclp4PQbk/photo.jpg";
                          }
                           googlePlusUserInfo.UserBidthday = GooglePlusUserData.birthday;
                          GooglePlusData.UserEmail = googlePlusUserInfo.UserEmail = GooglePlusUserData.email;
                         googlePlusUserInfo.UserFamilyName = GooglePlusUserData.family_name;
                        GooglePlusData.UserGender = googlePlusUserInfo.UserGender = GooglePlusUserData.gender;
                          googlePlusUserInfo.UserGivenName = GooglePlusUserData.given_name;
                         googlePlusUserInfo.UserId = GooglePlusUserData.id;
                        googlePlusUserInfo.UserLink = GooglePlusUserData.link;

                         Console.WriteLine("email==> " + GooglePlusUserData.email);
                          Console.WriteLine("birthday==> " + GooglePlusUserData.birthday);       

                           Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                         {
                               //logout();
                            });
                       }), GooglePlusProfileData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {

        }
    }

    void logout()
    {
        var url = "http://accounts.google.com/Logout";
        webBrowserGooglePlusLogin.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));           
        NavigationService.GoBack();           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article on Nokia is rather misleading about what it is doing. In particular, although it says the following method calls "the Google+ API", it is not. The Google+ call is commented out and the call is to the older (and deprecated) userinfo API:

```
//request for user prifile
   void RequestForUserProfile()
        {
          //  var urlProfile = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=" + thisApp.AccessToken;
            var urlProfile = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token="+thisApp.AccessToken;
            // web request user profile
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlProfile); 
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(this.ResponseCallbackProfile), request);
        }
```

If you comment out the urlProfile with the "userinfo" in the path and uncomment the one with "plus/v1/people", you will probably have better luck.

If this doesn't work, you may want to update your original question to show exactly what code you are using, what you're trying to do, and exactly where the error message you're getting is generated.

Comment: Yes.. Now i got the date of birth..!!!! I use this url `"https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=" + thisApp.AccessToken;`..